# Quelle est la faute dans le discours indirect dans cette phrase ?

Tags: inversion, discours-indirect

On nous donne que la phrase suivante contient une faute dans le discours indirect :

> Elle se demandait pourquoi le réveil n’avait-il pas sonné le matin.

Pourtant, je n'arrive pas à trouver la faute. Tout semble être correct. Le seule doute que j'ai est de savoir si « n’avait-il » devrait être conjugué au plus-que-parfait.

Que serait la faute ?

Comment: C'est pareil qu'en Anglais: en utilisant le discours indirect, on n'inverse pas le sujet et le verbe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La manière correcte de dire serait:

> Elle se demandait pourquoi le réveil n’avait pas sonné le matin.

C'est une histoire d'interrogation **directe ou indirecte**. Ici il s'agit d'un discours indirect, la transposition au style direct serait:

> Elle se demandait: "Pourquoi le réveil n'a-t-il pas sonné le matin ?"

Je ne suis pas capable d'expliquer pourquoi, mais **au discours indirect, on n'inverse pas le sujet avec le verbe**.

Quelques exemples:

> Je ne sais pas comment je vais faire.
>
> Je suis perdu, comment vais-je faire ?
>
> Nous nous demandons quand vous partirez.
>
> Quand partirez-vous ?